# png.h header file missing in zint barcode library:

Tags: c, barcode

I am currently using the zint barcode library for generating barcodes in my application. It works very fine and generates in .txt, .eps,.svg formats. It also supports ".png" format, but the problem is as the header file "png.h" is missing, im not able to generate barcodes in "png" format. 
The zint version i am using is 2.4.2
kindly help in this regard?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What platform are you developing on? It sounds like you need to install the PNG development libraries. For example, if you are on Ubuntu, 'apt-get install libpng-dev'.

Comment: Thank you Mike. i am developing on windows machine and linux machine. Let me check whether installing the PNG development libraries resolves my problem.

Comment: Hi, 

I have added png.h and its dependent headers (pconf.h,zlib.h). This helped me resolving the compilation error.But I am getting the following build error. Kindly help me in this please.


In function `writepng_error_handler':png.c:62: undefined reference to `png_get_error_ptr'
In function `png_pixel_plot':png.c:150: undefined reference to `png_create_write_struct'
png.c:156: undefined reference to `png_create_info_struct'
png.c:158: undefined reference to `png_destroy_write_struct'
png.c:171: undefined reference to `png_init_io'
....

Comment: This indicates that you have to link to the PNG library. On Linux, add '-lpng' to the final link command line.

Comment: Hi Mike,
Thank you again
Currently I am working in Windows machine. Do you have an alternative for windows.

Comment: I'm not too familiar with Windows dev environments. If you're using the MS IDE, you should be able to play with the project build options through some GUI. There should be a space for libraries to link against. Make sure the PNG library is in that list.

Comment: Hi Mike... I am able to create "png" formatted barcode image files in Windows machine. What i did is , added all the required header and implemetation files of "libpng" library and "zlib" library and used all of them in my application. Thanks a lot for your support.